# Merging two domain objects

Tags: domain-driven-design, factory

In the project I'm working on, we have an aggregate domain object.  The factory object handles the creation of the unique id for the object.  But there is a separate import process which creates the same object initially without the id. To add the imported object to the system, we are now forced to do a field by field copy to a new object since we can't just set the id for it for obvious reasons.  Could anyone suggest a better way of handling this situation?

Comment: The id property is supposed to be generated by lower level functions and is not supposed to be set by external objects so it is read only.

Answer (score 1):

Possibilities:

- If the import process allows it, inject your domain object when it is creating so it actually populates your object.
- Have your object's implementation be a wrapper around the one created by the import process. Change your factory accordingly.